# jQuery Waypoint not triggering at all in React project

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, jquery-waypoints

I'm using react to make an app and I just installed jquery and jquery-waypoints. 
I am trying to check the position of an element when it appears on the screen and if it isn't where I want it to be, then I'll jquery to reposition this element. I tried jquery.appear before jquery-waypoints and similarly, it simply wasn't triggering when I told it to.

This is what my code looks like:

```
...
var $ = require("jquery");
import 'jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js';
...
class Application extends SearchkitComponent<any, any> {

 render() {
   ...
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".rc-calendar").waypoint(function(){
       console.log("I showed up");   
     }, {context: 'div [data-reactroot=""]'});
   });

   /* I also tried without the context parameter above*/

    return (<div>
       ...
    );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('example2'));

/* I also tried jquery waypoint here and nothing happened as well */
```

The context parameter 'div [data...]' is a parent element to .rc-calendar (not direct parent). I don't get any errors and I am confident jquery-waypoints is installed correctly but no matter what I do, I never see the "I showed up" in my console. I also tried without $(document).ready.

Comment: I'd ditch jquery and look for a react solution in this case: http://brigade.github.io/react-waypoint/